# How to ignore the errors and continue to scrape using Python, Selenium?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm scraping real estate transaction data searching by neighborhoods and date periods, and some pages are empty that causes an error in my script.
For example, I'm running the script by executing the following code:

```
start_date = date(2020, 3, 1)
end_date = date(2020, 3, 10)
# Date duration, brooklyn every 5 days, manhattan every 3 days ...
neighbors = {'brooklyn': 5, 'manhattan': 3, 'staten_island': 10}
dict_generator(neighbors, start_date, end_date)
```

In here the dict_generator generates like:

```
brooklyn 03/01/2020 03/05/2020
brooklyn 03/06/2020 03/10/2020
manhattan 03/01/2020 03/03/2020
manhattan 03/04/2020 03/05/2020:
```

The following code starts scraping:

```
while True:
    try:
        for area in neighbors:
            for date in neighbors[area]:
                scrape(area, date[0], date[1])
                print(area, date[0], date[1])
    except:
        print("####CRASH " + area + " " + date[0] + " " + date[1])
        continue
```

scrape is the function that looks like this, and I'm using this to run in for-loop to scrape data for each date duration:

```
def scrape(neighborhood, startdate, enddate):

    # Status == Sold, 
        then click for Sold option

    # Neighborhoods
    if neighborhood == "manhattan":
        then click for manhattan
    if neighborhood == "staten_island":
        then click for staten_island
    if neighborhood == "brooklyn":
        then click for brooklyn

    # Click on the search

    # Export the listings

    # Back to Advanced Search
```

So basically, the for loop is doing:

```
scrape('brooklyn', 03/01/2020, 03/05/2020)
scrape('brooklyn', 03/06/2020, 03/10/2020)
scrape('manhattan', 03/01/2020, 03/03/2020)
....
```

And I'm scraping these data depends on the date duration and neighborhoods. But the problem is some date for a certain neighborhood like staten_island, has 0 transactions. And it causes an error and it stops scraping. Then I'm not sure exactly where I got the error from, so I have to re-run the script, scraping exact same data until I get the error. 
 
And I want to know how can I know exactly where I had the error, and re-start scraping from that specific date, rather than running the script from the beginning. 
I know this is not the full code, and not sure if I explain it well enough for anyone to understand, but I'd appreciate any advice or idea on how should I approach the problem...

Comment: Store each call to `scrape` (i.e. the area and the dates) in a file when the function is called the first time, then read that file on startup to see what the last call was. You can use `json.load` and `json.dump` to make something small work.

Comment: how about a try except ?

Comment: @SUREshamani I used the try and except, but wanted to know if I can somehow indicate this as an index, and start from a certain index when it's crashed... but not sure. Currently, I'm just using try/except to pass the error page..